# Running Commands In Split Konsole Via qdbus

Tags: konsole, qdbus

I'm trying to write a script that will create a split Konsole & run a bunch of commands, similar to tmuxinator.  Konsole has arguments to run commands in tabs, but the only way I found to do it in *splits* is via qdbus.  Per [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/hg7qkm/is_it_possible_to_split_konsole_via_a_shell_script/):

1. `qdbus org.kde.konsole-<pid> /konsole/MainWindow_1 org.kde.KMainWindow.activateAction split-view-left-right`
2. Find which session you want to run the command in
3. `qdbus org.kde.konsole-<pid> /Sessions/1 org.kde.konsole.Session.runCommand "echo"`

In step 3, if I use `Sessions/1` it runs the command in the 'first' split, as expected.  However,  I can't seem to figure out how to run a command in any of the others - any value other than '1' throws an error.

If anyone knows how to figure out the 'session' needed to run a command in any of the other (non-primary) splits, I'd greatly appreciate any pointers.  Sadly I'm completely inexperienced with qdbus, and haven't turned up much after quite a bit of Googling.